# URL Encode Alamofire GET params with SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to have Alamofire send the following parameter in a GET request but it's sending gibberish:

```
filters={"$and":[{"name":{"$bw":"duke"},"country":"gb"}]}
//www.example.com/example?filters={"$and":[{"name":{"$bw":"duke"},"country":"gb"}]}
//Obviously URL encoded
```

This is my code:

```
let jsonObject = ["$and":[["name":["$bw":string], "country":"gb"]]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
print(json)
```

outputs

> {
>     "$and" : [
>       {
>         "name" : {
>           "$bw" : "duke"
>         },
>         "country" : "gb"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

This is my params request:

```
let params = ["filters" : json.rawValue, "limit":"1", "KEY":"my_key"]
```

This is what AlamoFire is sending:

```
KEY=my_key&
filters[$and][][country]=gb&
filters[$and][][name][$bw]=duke&
limit=1
```

As you can see the filter parameter is a complete mess. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you copy here how you use Alamofire to send this request? Isn't this request sent using GET? Maybe you could try with POST method?

Comment: It has to be get. I use `.request(.GET, url, params)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default Alamofire encodes the parameters using Parameter List in the POST body. Try changing the encoding to `JSON`. This way Alamofire will serialize the dictionary as a JSON string as you expect:

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
// HTTP body: {"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": {"baz": "qux"}}
```

Or using your code:

```
let string = "duke"
let jsonObject = ["$and":[["name":["$bw":string], "country":"gb"]]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
let params = ["filters" : json.rawValue, "limit":"1", "KEY":"my_key"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: params, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { request, response, content, error in
        NSLog("Request: %@ - %@\n%@", request.HTTPMethod!, request.URL!, request.HTTPBody.map { body in NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "" } ?? "")
        if let response = response {
            NSLog("Response: %@\n%@", response, content ?? "")
        }
}
```

Gets the output:

```
Request: POST - http://httpbin.org/post
{"filters":{"$and":[{"name":{"$bw":"duke"},"country":"gb"}]},"limit":"1","KEY":"my_key"}
```

---

**EDIT: URL-Encoded JSON in the GET parameters**

If you want to send a URL-Encoded JSON in the GET parameters you have to generate first the JSON string and then pass it as a string in your parameters dictionary:

**SWIFT 1**

```
let string = "duke"
let jsonObject = ["$and":[["name":["$bw":string], "country":"gb"]]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)

// Generate the string representation of the JSON value
let jsonString = json.rawString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: nil)!
let params = ["filters" : jsonString, "limit": "1", "KEY": "my_key"]


Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: params)
    .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { request, response, content, error in
        NSLog("Request: %@ - %@\n%@", request.HTTPMethod!, request.URL!, request.HTTPBody.map { body in NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "" } ?? "")
        if let response = response {
            NSLog("Response: %@\n%@", response, content ?? "")
        }
}
```

**SWIFT 2**

```
let string = "duke"
let jsonObject = ["$and":[["name":["$bw":string], "country":"gb"]]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)

// Generate the string representation of the JSON value
let jsonString = json.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let params = ["filters" : jsonString, "limit": "1", "KEY": "my_key"]

Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/post", parameters: params)
    .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) { request, response, result in
        NSLog("Request: %@ - %@\n%@", request!.HTTPMethod!, request!.URL!, request!.HTTPBody.map { body in NSString(data: body, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "" } ?? "")
        switch result {
        case .Success(let value):
            NSLog("Response with content: %@", value)
        case .Failure(let data, _):
            NSLog("Response with error: %@", data ?? NSData())
        }
}
```

**SWIFT 3 and Alamofire 4.0**

```
let string = "duke"
let jsonObject = ["$and":[["name":["$bw":string], "country":"gb"]]]
let json = JSON(jsonObject)

// Generate the string representation of the JSON value
let jsonString = json.rawString(.utf8)!
let params = ["filters" : jsonString, "limit": "1", "KEY": "my_key"]

Alamofire.request("http://httpbin.org/post", method: .get, parameters: params)
    .responseString { response in
        #if DEBUG
            let request = response.request
            NSLog("Request: \(request!.httpMethod!) - \(request!.url!.absoluteString)\n\(request!.httpBody.map { body in String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" } ?? "")")
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("Response with content \(value)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Response with error: \(error as NSError): \(response.data ?? Data())")
            }
        #endif
}
```

This generates a GET request with the following URL:

```
http://httpbin.org/post?KEY=my_key&filters=%7B%22%24and%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22%24bw%22%3A%22duke%22%7D%2C%22country%22%3A%22gb%22%7D%5D%7D&limit=1
```

That URL-Decoded is:

```
http://httpbin.org/post?KEY=my_key&filters={"$and":[{"name":{"$bw":"duke"},"country":"gb"}]}&limit=1
```

Comment: Thanks (and I should have specified in the question sorry abou that) but I need to do a get request. Also it needs to look like this: "filters":"{"$and":[{"name":{"$bw":"duke"},"country":"gb"}]}","limit":"1","KEY":"my_key".... Not sure who wrote that API in the first place... I will make it clearer in the question.

Comment: So you want a JSON String as an URL-Encoded parameter in the GET URL. That changes completely the question. Take a look at my edit to see if that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! The one thing I had to edit was `let jsonString = json.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: .PrettyPrinted)!` as you can't supply `nil` and the first label is extraneous. I will edit it and will edit the question to make it clearer for others.

Comment: That works for me in Swift 1 and iOS 8. I'll check for XCode 7, Swift 2 and iOS 9.

Comment: I'm on 7 / iOS9... Will not touch your code then!! Will award the points as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: @MobileBloke added Swift 3 version

Comment: Thanks - helped me debug the issue - brill.  so its just UTF8 converted, which is why we can't just print it out.

Comment: One of the better posts I've seen in swift on SO, thanks for posting.