# Alamofire GET request with parameters, -> "extra argument in call"

Tags: swift, get, alamofire

I am trying to make a GET request using Alamofire with parameters to a backend written in python.

I tried several ways of doing this with no success and i read somewhere that i should remove parameters in order to get a clean GET request and it worked.

I still need to use parameters so i saw this post:  [Get JSON result with GET request and parameters with Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641243/get-json-result-with-get-request-and-parameters-with-alamofire)

Trying the solution there, Xcode gives me an instant error: `extra argument in call`

This is how it looks like when i get my error:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: ["test":"te"]).responseJSON {
            (responseObject) -> Void in

            print(responseObject)

            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error: NSError = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have wrong order of parameters and for parameter *method* you forgot to write parameter name.

Change this

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: ["test":"te"]).responseJSON {
```

to this

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: ["test":"te"]).responseJSON {
```

You can anytime check function parameters when you jump to its definition. Just hold <kbd>Command</kbd> and click to function and select **Jump to Definition**

[image]

now you can see request method parameters

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the tip to see how to see the definition. will vote as answer when i can