# How do I see Alamofire Request?

Tags: swift, debugging, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire for an Api that has a Json body and a header requirement that needs Basic Authentication. When I test the call in Postman it works fine, however with AlamoFire I am getting a server error.

I am trying to see what the call is that's going out from Alamofire - but I can't seem to see it:  (this is the code I am using)

edit:

**Error is below**

> ["errors": { }, "errorMessages": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x6000000035c0>( Internal server error ) ]

**Request is below**

```
  Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: paramsEncoded, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            print(response.request) // This returns just the url eg "http://api.com
            print(response.request?.httpBody) // This returns `Optional(85 bytes)`
        })
```

I assume the request is not being created properly, but would be useful to understand what I should be seeing.

Edit: this line helped from the other question : 
`NSLog("Request: \(request!.httpMethod!) - \(request!.url!.absoluteString)\n\(request!.httpBody.map { body in String(data: body, encoding: .utf8) ?? "" } ?? "")")`

Thanks to the question I have linked to as a duplicate for the help.

Comment: Can you show me your error?

Comment: added the error, thanks

Comment: Have you try to print `response.result.value` ?

Comment: This other question helped me to see that Alamofire was changing the order of the json body. link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32595517/url-encode-alamofire-get-params-with-swiftyjson/32649785?noredirect=1#comment67440290_32649785 suggest we mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Done. - is that what you meant Ekta?

Comment: But it was none of the answers below.. it was on another question. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print the whole request like this :

```
let request = Alamofire.request(endpoint, method: .post, parameters: paramsEncoded, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        print(response.request) 
        print(response.request?.httpBody)
    })

print("REQUEST = \(request)")
```

I'm not sure you can get any more info than that though.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add headers with your request.

```
let urlString = "https://httpbin.org/get"
let headers = ["Authorization": "123456"]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["foo": "bar"],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
    print(response.result.value)
}
```

Comment: Hi - thanks - but I did add headers already if you look above - I have included the header details to help